# Use private docker registry with Authentication in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-registry

**How can I teach my Jenkisfile to login via basic auth in this setup?**

I'm using a custom docker image for my Jenkins build. 
As described in the documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) I defined a docker agent like so:

```
pipeline {
agent { 
    docker {
        image 'registry.az1:5043/maven-proto'
        registryUrl 'https://registry.az1'
        args '-v /var/jenkins_home/.m2:/root/.m2'
    }
}
options {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr:'10'))
}

stages {
    stage ('Build') {
        steps{
            sh ...
        }
    }

    stage ('Test') {
        steps {
            sh ...
        }
    } 

     stage ('Deploy') {
        steps {
            sh ...
        }
    }
}

post {
    always {
        echo 'Clean up workspace'
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

}

If I use the following agent setup:

```
pipeline {
agent { 
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.az1', 'registry_login'){
        image 'registry.az1:5043/maven-proto'
        registryUrl 'https://registry.az1'
        args '-v /var/jenkins_home/.m2:/root/.m2'
    }
}
```

The execution of the pipeline fails with the following exception:

```
WorkflowScript: 3: Too many arguments for map key "withRegistry" @ line 3, column 16.
       docker.withRegistry('https://registry.az1', 'registry_login'){
              ^

WorkflowScript: 3: Invalid agent type "withRegistry" specified. Must be one of [docker, dockerfile, label, any, none] @ line 3, column 16.
           docker.withRegistry('https://registry.az1', 'registry_login'){
                  ^
```

The problem is that the used registry requires a basic auth login. The registry runs behind a nginx reverse proxy using [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/) configuration.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As specified in [Using a custom registry](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry), you can specify the credentials and registry url to use as such:

```
docker.withRegistry('https://registry.az1', 'credentials-id') {
    ...
}
```

You need to create a Jenkins credentials object which will contain the credentials for the repository and give it a name to replace `credentials-id` above.

**Update:**

For declarative pipelines, the syntax is as such:

```
agent { 
    docker {
        image 'registry.az1:5043/maven-proto'
        registryUrl 'https://registry.az1'
        registryCredentialsId 'credentials-id'
        args '-v /var/jenkins_home/.m2:/root/.m2'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier. Where in the Jenkisfile would this go exactly? 
Currently, I am defining the agent at the root level so that the definition is reused for each stage.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for declarative pipeline. Information on specifying `registryUrl` and `registryCredentialsId` are missing in the docker pipeline documentation (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) or the docker section under agent documentation (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent). How did you find them? Through the original Jira? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39684

Comment: Never managed to get this to work. Chose to add the registry in Configure System --> `Pipeline Model Definition` section --> `Docker registry URL` and  `Registry credentials` parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! For those using Google's GCR, use ```gcr:credentials-id``` and it should work.

Comment: @haridsv - hopefully you were not urgently waiting for an answer. :)
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: `credentials-id` aren't your credentials, it's the id of the saved credential (like your hub.docker.com username/token) stored as username/token in jenkins.