# Jenkins pipeline fails for docker login to pull public image from dockerhub

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, sonatype, nexus3

With the below declarative pipeline code i am trying to pull an public image from dockerhub in jenkins however it fails with below error.

```
pipeline {  
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ubuntu:latest'
            label "jenkins-slave-01"
            }
    }
    stages {    
        stage('Build') {    
            steps { 
                sh 'cat /etc/lsb-release'
            }   
        }   
        stage('Deploy') {   
            steps { 
                sh 'cat /etc/lsb-release'
            }   
        }           
    }   
}
```

**Jenkins console output:-**

```
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
Using the existing docker config file.Removing blacklisted property: auths$ docker login -u test -p ******** https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: docker login failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Even pulling public images from dockerhub required authentication in jenkins? As i have already private registry(nexus) configured in jenkins in `Declarative Pipeline (Docker)` section, along with that i would want to pull public images from dockerhub.

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029379/use-private-docker-registry-with-authentication-in-jenkinsfile/49029565

Comment: @SouravAtta, In my case i have already private registry configured in jenkins, along with that i would want to pull public images from dockerhub.

Comment: Which private registry you are using ex. Nexus ?

Comment: Yes nexus we are using as private registry.

Comment: Have you done the settings like this in Nexus ? https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-3-docker-images

Comment: So far i have private repository in our nexus, Now in order to download the public images from dockerhub, i need to setup`proxy repo` in our nexus?

Comment: can you provide extra information about the OS of the Jenkins server?, also if your server os is Linux, are you able to pull images with the Jenkins user from docker hub on the command line? and finally do you have any plugin that might be messing around with your docker agent?, Jenkins server version might be also useful.

Comment: Yes correct. Follow the steps in the blog and then if you have setup everything correct, it will work

Comment: @Ikaro0, `Jenkins Master OS is Centos-8.2, Jenkins Version is - 2.227.1 LTS` and `Slave OS is Ubuntu-14.04(LTS)` Yes on command line able to pull the images. I have `docker` plugin installed in my jenkins

Comment: @SouravAtta, As per the blog i have enabled `proxy repo` & `group repo`. Now in jenkins with above given pipeline code i am getting following error in console - `Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://nexustool.company.net/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found` i am not sure why it is connecting to `v2` end point.

Comment: Ok, the question here would be in my opinion, why is it using https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/? what is the output of "docker system info|grep Registry" I think it should be something like index.docker.io/v1/

Comment: Output as follows, ` $ docker system info|grep Registry`
`WARNING: No swap limit support`
`Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/`

Comment: Then, if you execute docker pull from your OS command line you are going to be pulling from index.docker.io/v1, why is Jenkins trying to pull from the v2 registry? you might have some configuration on Jenkins pointing to this "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"

Comment: Exactly. Currently i have docker plugin installed in jenkins. In `Manage Jenkins > Configure Systems > Declarative Pipeline (Docker) - Docker registry URL` (I have provided our private registry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the exchange that we have on the comments from your initial question, we can get that your docker configuration on the "declarative pipeline" plugin is pointing out to a pull-through cache configuration rather than the public docker registry and you can see some info about that here https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/.

If you want to use the one configured on the plugin you should be able to configure credentials to access that repository and then select those credentials to be used with this private repository, and giving context for ppl coming to have a look at this problem, the plugin that you mentioned on your command has the following configuration:
[image]

on Registry credentials do you have something selected?
In my case I use artifactory repository but not configuring it with this plugin but with credentials configured on Jenkins and calling the full repository URL when declaring the agent on my pipelines.

Maybe you can avoid using the pipeline configured on the pipeline stating the full docker URL for downloading ubuntu instead of only the container+version like:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'registry.hub.docker.com/library/ubuntu:latest'
        label "jenkins-slave-01"
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes if i keep my `Declarative pipeline (Docker)` URl and credentials `none`  `docker {
image 'ubuntu:latest'  }` it works. However i will try to configure `Registry as a pull through cache` method to use private registry to pull the public images from dockerhub.

Comment: has the question being answered or do you still have problems downloading docker images for your agent?

Comment: Thanks a lot `Ikaro0` and `Sourav Atta`. I didn't know that Nexus even i can it for caching the images from dockerhub.

Answer (score 0):

This is still broken with no good workaround, but here is an ugly hack.  If you can use the docker cli on the host, you can circumvent Jenkins' docker client.

*Note*: This assumes you have linux hosts which execute your docker containers.  If you have a different kind of setup this may not work for you.

#### Manually pull the image onto the host first

```
pipeline {  
    agent any // Get an agent.  You may want to define a label here.
    stages {    
        stage('pull') {    
            steps { 
                sh 'docker pull ubuntu:latest' // Pull the image down to the agent.
            }   
        }   
        stage('docker') { // Nested stages all run on the docker agent
            agent {
                docker {
                    image "ubuntu:latest" // It will find the image locally
                    reuseNode true        // important!
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage('build') {
                    steps { 
                        sh 'cat /etc/lsb-release'
                    }
                }
                stage('deploy') {
                    steps { 
                        sh 'cat /etc/lsb-release'
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    }   
}
```