# Run docker login for several registries in Jenkins agent docker section

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have an issue with Jenkins pipeline and Docker.
Pipeline is configured the following way:

- It chooses agent with Docker
- It runs a container with maven and additional arguments. Image is taken from docker_custom_registry_1.
- Inside the container it runs mvn clean install
- Maven build runs integration tests with TestContainers
- Integration tests start some containers from different registries: docker central registry, docker_custom_registry_1, docker_custom_registry_2.
  Tests will detect that they're inside the container (mvn-3.5.4-jdk:latest) and will go "up" and start containers in Docker, on the agent itself.
  See https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            registryUrl 'https://docker_custom_registry_1'
            registryCredentialsId 'custom-credential-1'

            image 'docker_custom_registry_1/mvn-3.5.4-jdk:latest'
            args '-v /u01/jenkins/m2-repo:/m2-repo -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage("Initialize") {
            steps {
                script {
                    //...
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                script {
                    // During the build tests with TestContainers will be run.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Issue description:

Custom registries requires custom authentication - via `docker login`.
When I specify registry in pipeline/agent/docker/registryUrl and registryCredentialsId, pipeline executes docker login for this registry.
But I cannot find the way how to execute `docker login` for the second registry.

- Tried to run `docker login` in script block of the step. But all steps and scripts are executed inside the maven container, so it does not work.
- Tried to specify two `registryUrl`'s in the pipeline/agent/docker, but it uses only the last one specified.
- Tried to find a way to run some script before running base container - did not find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use private docker registry with Authentication in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029379/use-private-docker-registry-with-authentication-in-jenkinsfile)

Comment: `-v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD` Jenkins already does that, you can take it out.

Comment: @KamilCuk no it does not. It describes how to authenticate custom registry, but not how to authenticate in TWO or more registries.

Comment: I do not fully understand. Just `docker login` then. `But all steps and scripts are executed inside the maven container, so it does not work.` Why?

Comment: @KamilCuk because it does not make a sense to execute docker login inside the container. Container does not have any docker in it.

Comment: `because it does not make a sense to execute docker login inside the container` why? `Container does not have any docker in it` It does, you do `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` and logins are stored locally in ~/.docker/config. Even if it does not have docker "in it", you can specify `DOCKER_HOST=` and connect to remote docker via port or SSH. If you can _connect_ to docker, you can docker login, and then you can docker push, which is what I understand you want to do.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've got your point, thank you. But for some reason it does not work for me. I'll try again.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks once again. I've found the solution. You was right, about sharing docker.sock, but I was missing Docker executable inside the container. And to solve it I simply mounted Docker executable to container. And it works perfectly for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KamilCuk mentioned, mounting docker.sock by `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` gives an ability to access the host's Docker. But I was missing the Docker executable inside the container.

So I solved it the following way:

- I added a parameter to share docker executable: `-v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`
- I added a script into the pipeline step to execute docker login: `docker.withRegistry('https://docker_custom_registry_2', 'docker_custom_registry_2_credential') {}`

So the final pipeline should look like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            registryUrl 'https://docker_custom_registry_1'
            registryCredentialsId 'custom-credential-1'

            image 'docker_custom_registry_1/mvn-3.5.4-jdk:latest'
            args '-v /u01/jenkins/m2-repo:/m2-repo -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Logging into https://docker_custom_registry_2'
                    docker.withRegistry('https://docker_custom_registry_2', 'docker_custom_registry_2_credential) {
                        // Run tests with Docker here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```